# Render Pattern in list view for "custom field types" sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, xslt, custom-field-types

I have developed a custom field type which will show the link to the "workflow history list" in the list (It's a column in the list).

It works fine in sharepoint 2007 site. when i migrate the code to sharepoint 2010, everything works fine but in list view the link is appearing as text with all HTML formatting.

In Display form it works fine. But in list view it displays all the href values, when I put CAMLRendering true in my xml file. how I can overcome it. i read that i need to create a .xsl file for it as the render pattern is obsolete and it will not work for list views.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *RenderPattern* is [obsolete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff623047%28v=office.14%29.aspx) starting from version 14 (SharePoint 2010). So, RenderPattern  does not affect how *Field* is rendered in *List View*.

In order to define Custom Rendering for a Custom Field, please see [How to: Customize the Rendering of a Field on a List View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff606773.aspx)

---

### Brief description.

1. Create XSLT style sheet for rendering a custom field type. In your
   case XSLT style sheet  would look like shown below:

   ```
   <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp"
                   version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt"
                   xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"
                   xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20"
                   xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer"
                   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                   xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                   xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
                   xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
     <xsl:template match ="FieldRef[@Name='YourCustomFieldInternalName']" mode="URL_body">
       <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
       <!-- Hyperlink for History List goes here --> 
     </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```

   Note:  a)you have to specify match attribute, so that the template
   matches only fields with the exact internal name of your custom
   field `match="FieldRef[@Name='YourCustomFieldInternalName']"` Also
   instead of Field Internal Name you could specify match attribute for
   Field ID, like this
   `match="FieldRef[@ID='5a14d1ab-1513-48c7-97b3-657a5ba6c742']"`

   b)you have to specify correct `mode`. It value depends on the [Field
   type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldtype.aspx), use the following mapping info as guidance: 
   [SPFieldComputed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcomputed.aspx) (Computed_body), [SPFieldUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduser.aspx)(User_body),
   [SPFieldText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldtext.aspx)(Text_body) and etc.
2. Save your XSLT stylesheet, I recommend to use the following naming
   convention:

   > fldtypes_YourFieldTypeName.xsl
3. Deploy it to `%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\XSL`

Comment: I didn't find any information about 1.b) elsewhere so this was pretty helpful, however I needed to change `@Name` to `@FieldType` to work in my case. Maybe someone will find it helpful.